# SoundCloud Autoplay in iFrame has Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, iframe, soundcloud, autoplay

this page http://falsefeatures.com/aBookForPrivateReading/PlayHeavyWater should autoplay as I understand it.

the code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/108973626&amp;color=9900EE&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_artwork=false"></iframe>
```

the audio does play if button clicked and I can change the button color and show or hide the artwork, as you'd expect. but no autoplay?

I've simplified for debug purposes but I have another page which I'd swear was autoplaying last week just fine. I have tried different browsers, computers, connections: what gives?

~Marqso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link auto plays fine for me on Chrome.

It won't work on iOS devices though – there's a limitation on Apple's side that prevents media from auto playing in order to save on user's traffic.

Comment: Thanks gryzzly. it does now, for me, too! It did and then it didn't for at least two days and now it does, no changes to the code... Does anyone know if this could possibly have been an issue on the part of my hosting service (godaddy) of if it might have been an temporary issue with soundcloud?

Comment: points here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867040/unexplained-multi-day-lapse-in-soundcloud-iframe-autoplay-option-hosting-is

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a regression on our part and was fixed last week.

https://twitter.com/flaneur/status/398439823234846720